# What/where are the DOM button icons for the Mobile XPages controls?

Tags: dojo, xpages, dojox.mobile

I've been experimenting with adding Dojo Attributes to the XPages Mobile controls and discovered a couple of interesting icon classes like mblDomButtonCheck and mblDomButtonArrow, for eaxmaple:

```
<xe:djxmLineItem id="djxmLineItem7" label="P2 to P3"
                rightText="flip" moveTo="#appPage3" transition="flip">
                <xe:this.dojoAttributes>
                    <xp:dojoAttribute name="arrowClass" value="mblDomButtonCheck">
                    </xp:dojoAttribute>
                    <xp:dojoAttribute name="rightIcon2" value="mblDomButtonCheck">
                    </xp:dojoAttribute>
                    <xp:dojoAttribute name="icon" value="mblDomButtonArrow">
                    </xp:dojoAttribute>
                </xe:this.dojoAttributes>
 </xe:djxmLineItem>
```

But other than the mention of these two icon classes at [the Dojo reference site](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/mobile/ListItem.html) I have not been able to find any other documentation or listing for other available icon classes.

Anyone know where I can get a listing or reference for the available mblDomButton icon classes?

Comment: Here's a (small?) list: http://www.caleblloyd.com/software/dojo-dojox-mobile-mbldombutton-icon-list-android-iphone/

Comment: Thanks Per, your link led me to this reference at the Dojo reference site: http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.9.1/dojo-release-1.9.1/dojox/mobile/tests/test_domButtons.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the lead Per ... based on your comment I found a more extensive listing of mblDomButton icon classes here:

[for iphone](http://www.caleblloyd.com/scripts/dojo-mobile/iphone-icons.html)

and here:

[for android](http://www.caleblloyd.com/scripts/dojo-mobile/android-icons.html)